# Running Python Scripts

Tags: python

`Python35-32` is installed on my PC running Windows 7 64-bit, in the directory ‘C:/Program Files (x86)/Python35-32’.

My Python scripts are installed in:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Python35-32/Scripts/pyscripts
```

The System Environment Variable ‘Path’ includes:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Python35-32’
```

and:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Python35-32/Scripts/pyscripts
```

The System Variable ‘PATHEXT ‘ is:

```
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY
```

The User  Environment Variable ‘PATH’ is:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Python35-32;C:/Program Files (x86)/Python35-32/Scripts/pyscripts
```

The Python current working directory is;

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Python35-32
```

There are several scripts in the directory ‘pyscripts’: ‘CleanupStops.py’ and ‘concord.py’ are two of them.

Upon entering the following at the Python prompt:

```
>>> CleanupStops.py`
```

The following error message is returned;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File “<stdin>”, line 1, in < module.
NameError: name ‘CleanupStops’ is not defined
Invoking another script results in the same error message.
```

I can run the scripts from PowerShell if I change the current working directory to `C:/Program Files (x86)/Python35-32/Scripts/pyscripts`.

I have researched similar issues which were resolved by:

1. Inserting the correct path into the environment variables
2. Including the file extension `.py` and/or
3. Changing the current working directory to where the scripts are located.

I have incorporated these, but still receive a `NameError` as described above.

I would also like to run python scripts from PowerShell without having to change the current working directory every time I open PowerShell. I have not found advice on how to do this. How do I resolve these problems?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your scripts folder to the PYTHONPATH environment variable to allow calling scripts in python from any location [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion;  I have done that but continue to get the NameError message

Comment: Hmmm... maybe just confirm the environment variables are correctly configured in PowerShell  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx  Does it work in regular windows command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running two versions of python?

I would use a batch file. To try

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\the\location

python file_name.py

pause
```

I'd use pause just to see if it works. Remove it if that works.